# How to set QComboBox to item from item's text in PyQt/PySide

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, qcombobox

Is it possible to set QComboBox to an item knowing only an item's text value? I am trying to avoid looping through `for i in range(myCombobox.count())` just to find an item's index so it could be used to set the current index.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes, there is [QComboBox.findText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#findText), which will return the index of the matched item (or `-1`, if there isn't one). By default, the search does exact, case-sensitive matching, but you can tweak the behaviour by passing some [match-flags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#MatchFlag-enum) as the second argument. For example, to do case-*insensitive* matching:

```
    index = combo.findText(text, QtCore.Qt.MatchFixedString)
    if index >= 0:
         combo.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

There is also an equivalent [findData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#findData) method that matches by the item's data.

Comment: The case-sensitive is actually what I need. But that's good to know a search settings are tweakable. Thanks again!

Comment: how about substring? should I post another question?

Comment: @greendino Please consult the links in my answer, which will show you all the options. It sounds like you just need to use `Qt.MatchContains`.